# Can I use Grub as my boot manager on a HDD drive installing Kali? When I put in the USB(live) or not it says I have no boot manager

Tags: hard-drive, installation, kali-linux, bootloader

I have two hard drives. One is an SSD with windows. The other I am trying to put Kali on. I figured the easy way was just to take out the SSD with windows temporarily. Now when I try to run my install it tells me I have no boot manager. How do I add one for Linux on the clean 1TB HDD for the install? Also, what do I use? Grub? And where do I get the download I can run off Rufus(USB)?

Answer (score 1):

Kali Linux is a specialized Debian based Linux distro NOT intended to be installed let alone used as daily driver.

That said, and because Debian based, it supports BIOS or UEFI modes perfectly fine.

Any computer with Windows preinstalled since 2012, at least, is UEFI and the factory OS is therefore installed in the proper and recommended UEFI mode. Ubuntu, a sister distro also Debian based, has a nice and easy to follow [UEFI guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI) which is applicable to any similar distro. Also at the AskUbuntu part of Stack Exchange there's already [a very popular Q&A](https://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/how-do-i-install-ubuntu-alongside-a-pre-installed-windows-with-uefi) with everything users must know to install a successful Windows+Linux dual-bot in UEFI mode.

In a nutshell:

No, you shouldn't remove the SSD with Windows as it contains the ESP (EFI System Partition) where the Linux installer expects to save Grub. Assuming the installer was booted in the correct UEFI mode and the target drive is blank and preferably GPT the "install alongside" option should do everything automatically. At most, users may need to open UEFI settings > Boot and change the boot order / OS selection to "Kali" instead of the default "Windows..." in order to boot the Grub menu which in turn should have the options to boot Kali or Windows (by chainloading to the Windows EFI bootloader).

Of course, users always have the option to do "something else" and configure the installation with different partitioning provided the ESP (in the primary drive) is also selected as such.

**Finally, any Kali user is expected to know this and a LOT more than what this question suggests. Kali is NOT a distro for newbies that don't have yet a solid knowledge about everything discussed above AND solid Linux fundamentals.**